# Embarcadero C++Builder Could not bind socket. Address and port are already in use

Tags: c++, tcp, server, indy, esp8266

My main purpose is actaully communicate ESP8266 and a Server. I had written a Server with Embarcadero Rad Studio 10 Seattle using C++. But the server is only working with Local IP addresses like "127.0.0.1","127.10.0.10" etc. When I had tried to use "192.168.4.1" as an IP address, i got an error "Could not bind socket. Address and port are already in use". You can see pictures below. How can I fix it?

[image: Server with local IP address]

Server with local IP address

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D36iQ.jpg]

Error situation

Comment: The same issue. Have you found any satisfactory solution?